# Combining all tabs in a google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I've got a large google sheet with multiple tabs. Each tab contains a different "deal" and a list of salesfolks and what their commission percentage is for that deal, as well as their total cash commission. Each "deal" tab is structured identically, the only information that changes is

1. Which salespeople are on the deal
2. What their commission % is for the deal (1 person could have different percentages on different deals)

I want to create a separate sheet, or separate tab, whichever is easier, that shows *every* salesperson and what their total cash take-home was across *all* deals.

To do this, I somehow need to do a simple lookup *across tabs*. This is simple enough if you know all the tab names such as [in this example](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/8201106/how-do-you-consolidate-multiple-tabs-on-sheets-into-one-master-list?hl=en) with the query formula,
`=QUERY({Watershed!A2:L;Timeline!A2:L;Deal5!A2:L;Excellence!A2:L;Bradshaw!A2:L;'O''Contractors'!A2:L;Thoroughfare!A2:L;Deal6!A2:L;Novi!A2:L;Denault!A2:L},"select * where Col1 is not null",0)`

but in my scenario new tabs are being constantly added. So, while I can standardize the tab names, move them into their own sheet, etc. I will always have 1 tab/sheet per deal (though each tab will follow the same format).
Is there any way to merge data across *all* tabs in a google sheet without explicitly stating each tab name in the formula? I'm a decent programmer so perhaps [App Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) could help with this if it's not possible with built-in formulas?

**TL;DR:** Merging data across all tabs dynamically in GSheets, is it possible?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Merging data across all tabs dynamically in GSheets, is it possible?`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? For example, when a new sheet is inserted, when is the data inserted? I cannot understand when you want to merge the data. I apologize for this. And, in your situation, is the order of merged data important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve all values from all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet and want to merge all values, and want to put the merged values into a specific sheet in the same Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script 1:

In this sample script, your formula is used. The formula is created by retrieving all sheets. Before you use this script, please set the variables of `destinationSheetName` and `excludeSheetNames`.

```js
function myFunction1() {
  const destinationSheetName = "main"; // Please set the destination sheet name.
  const excludeSheetNames = [destinationSheetName, "Sheet2"]; // If you have the exclude sheets, please set the sheet name here.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ssId = ss.getId();
  const ranges = ss.getSheets().reduce((ar, s) => {
    const sheetName = s.getSheetName();
    if (!excludeSheetNames.includes(sheetName)) {
      ar.push(`'${sheetName}'!A2:L`);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []).join(";");
  const formula = `=QUERY({${ranges}},"select * where Col1 is not null",0)`;
  ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName).clearContents().getRange("A1").setFormula(formula);
}
```

- When this script is run, all sheets except for `excludeSheetNames` are retrieved and create a formula, and put the created formula into the cell "A1" of the sheet "destinationSheetName".
- In this case, even when the sheet is inserted and the sheet name is changed, the latest sheets are used because all sheets are checked when the script is run. I thought that this might be your expected situation.

#### Sample script 2:

In this sample script, the values are directly put. In order to reduce the process cost, Sheets API is used. So, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced?hl=ja#enable_advanced_services).

And, please set the variables of `destinationSheetName` and `excludeSheetNames`.

```js
function myFunction2() {
  const destinationSheetName = "main"; // Please set the destination sheet name.
  const excludeSheetNames = [destinationSheetName, "Sheet2"]; // If you have the exclude sheets, please set the sheet name here.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ssId = ss.getId();
  const ranges = ss.getSheets().reduce((ar, s) => {
    const sheetName = s.getSheetName();
    if (!excludeSheetNames.includes(sheetName)) {
      ar.push(`'${sheetName}'!A2:L`);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  const { valueRanges } = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(ssId, { ranges });
  const values = valueRanges.flatMap(({ values }) => values);
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.clear({}, ssId, destinationSheetName);
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values }, ssId, destinationSheetName, { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });
}
```

- When this script is run, all values from sheets except for `excludeSheetNames` are retrieved and merged, and the merged values are put into the sheet "destinationSheetName". In this sample, before the merged values are put. the sheet "destinationSheetName" is cleared.
- In this case, even when the sheet is inserted and the sheet name is changed, the latest sheets are used because all sheets are checked when the script is run. I thought that this might be your expected situation.

#### Note:

- About your additional request of `TL;DR: Merging data across all tabs dynamically in GSheets, is it possible?`, unfortunately, I cannot imagine that situation as I have already mentioned in my comment. For example, if you want to run this script when the Spreadsheet is opened when you install the OnOpen trigger to the function, this can be achieved. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- For example, when the installable OnChange trigger is used, the script can be automatically run by checking `changeType` of `INSERT_GRID` of the event object. But, in this case, I think that the data is not included in the new sheet. I'm worried about this situation.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)